# Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a set of vector. Is it true that if every $v_i$ is L.I with $v_j$ for all $i,j$, then $\{v_1,..,v_n\}$ are L.I?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, independence

In a test I made the following argument:

For a set of vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, if every $v_i$ is L.I with $v_j$ for all $i,j$, then $\{v_1,..,v_n\}$ are L.I. Is this argument correct? For me it looked like it was true, but my professor said it was wrong.

Comment: The question is ill posed. Should be "if $\{v_i,v_j\}$ is LI whenever $i\ne j$ then $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is LI

Answer (score 4):

No...

$v_1=(1,0), v_2=(0,1), v_3=(1,1)$

Are "pairwise" linearly independent. But together do not form a linearly independent set.

Comment: Any 3 pairwise linearly independent vectors work for this in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Comment: Any set of three vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes - I'm saying that any 3 pairwise linearly independant vectors are a counterexample

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a generalization to David's answer below,  if you have ANY two linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2$,   then $v_1, v_2,v_1+v_2$ will be pairwise linearly independent but as a trio they are very dependent!